# Android bitmap unexplained memory usage

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have a 2550 x 1700 (W x H) jpg photo. After loading the bitmap as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#load-bitmap) memory usage increases by around 200MB. Which is much more than the expected 35MB (2550 * 1700 * 8 bytes/pixel) for the full size photo.

What am I doing wrong?

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

bg_bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.p7, width, height);
img_bg_delay.setImageBitmap(bg_bmp);
```

[image]

Comment: What specific resource directory contains `p7.jpg`?

Comment: It is found in `/res/drawable`

Comment: Move it into `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/`. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, and so your image will be upscaled on higher density devices.

Comment: Thanks - this brought memory usage to expected levels (20 MB). But now there is another problem: the graphics memory is not released after activity is destroyed. Even after doing `bitmap.recycle()` and triggering GC

Comment: That's normal. Resources are cached by the framework.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to ensure these memory resources are freed up after the parent activity is destroyed? I want to reduce the resource footprint of the app.

Comment: "Is there a way to ensure these memory resources are freed up after the parent activity is destroyed?" -- AFAIK, those resources will remain in memory until the process is terminated. "I want to reduce the resource footprint of the app" -- then do not have this image as a resource, since you do not completely control the memory. Package it in `assets/` and read it in from a stream obtained from `AssetManager` and its `open()` method.

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried the assets technique and `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` and the graphics memory is still never released. I've also tried loading it from server with Picasso, using `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)` and same result. The app has a background service but LeakCanary does not find any leaks

Comment: Generate a heap dump, find your big memory allocation, and see who is holding onto it.

Comment: Dumping heap - profiler reports a total of ~100MB, opening in Eclipse MAT shows ~18MB (keep unreachable objects is on). No bitmaps in sight

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug in the Studio profiler, or (somewhat less likely) in MAT.

Comment: Profiler figures are confirmed by the Average Memory usage figures in device app settings :(

Comment: Average memory is an average. The only way it would not reflect this large image is if you never loaded that large image.